# Jquery, tablednd and ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, post

So, im using $.tableDnD.serialize() function, to get the current order of the Table TR-s, and want to post to a php function alongside with another variable.

```
    $("#articlestable").tableDnD({
        onDragClass: "drag",
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            $.post('<?php echo HTML_ROOT; ?>/admin/cikkek/updateOrder/', {

                pagesid : "1",
                arr : $.tableDnD.serialize()

            });
        }
    });
```

If i am sending the serialized data only, there is no problem with the access.
According to firebug the sent data:

```
arr articlestable[]=1&articlestable[]=2&articlestable[]=4&articlestable[]=3
pagesid 1
```

The main question, how can i get the data in php?
I thought:

```
$pagesid = $_POST["pagesid"];
$orderarr = $_POST["arr"]["articlestable"];
```

Thanks for help, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is parse string. I could be wrong.

```
<?php
  $arr = array();
  $str = $_POST['arr'];
  parse_str($str, $arr);
?>
```

In doing this, you should be able to then access the array as ->

```
echo $arr[0]; // outputs 1
echo $arr[1]; //outputs 2
echo $arr[2]; //outputs 4
```

So on and so forth.

**EDIT**

I should also note that using this method, you can still access your pageid by using the following:

```
echo $arr['pagesid'];
```